# Simple query takes minutes to execute on a killed/inactive session

Tags: c++, performance, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to add simple failover functionality to my application that talks to Oracle <strike>8</strike> 11 database. To test that my session is up I issue a simple query (select 1 from dual).

Now when I try to simulate a network outage by killing my Oracle session by doing "alter system kill session 'sid,serial';" and execute this test query it takes up to 5 minutes for the application to process it and return error from Execute method (I'm using OCI API, C++):

> Tue Feb 21 21:22:47 HKT 2012: Checking connection with test query...
>
> Tue Feb 21 21:28:13 HKT 2012: Warning - OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: 3113: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
>
> Tue Feb 21 21:28:13 HKT 2012: Test connection has failed, attempting to re-establish connection...

If I kill session with the 'immediate' keyword at the end of the query, then the test query returns error instantly.

Question 1: why it takes 5 minutes to execute my query? Are there any Oracle/PMON logs that can shed some light on what is happening during this delay?

Question 2: is it a good choice to use 'alter system kill session ' to simulate network failure? How close the outcomes of this query to a real-world network failure between application and Oracle DB?

Update:

Oracle version:

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Comment: Oracle 8 database? Wow! The extended support for 8i expired 31st December 2006 and 8 ran out 30th June 2003! You might want to consider recommending an upgrade to this decade.

Comment: What version of the Oracle client are you using?  What operating system (and operating system version) are both the database and the client running on?  And what is the 4-digit version of the Oracle database you're using?  To Ollie's point, if we assume "Oracle 8" means "Oracle 8.1.7.4+" and not something even earlier, that's been out of extended support for a *long* time.  If anything in the environment is less than a decade old, you're likely going to have compatibility issues that could be compounding your problems.

Comment: @Ollie, I'm sorry it must be a misprint. Here's what I see when I connect to the database via sqlplus:


Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Comment: `select 1 from dual` should complete in milliseconds; are you sure you're killing the correct session, or are you "killing" an inactive session?

Comment: @Ben, yes, I'm sure I'm killing the right session.    

But indeed it could be the case that the session I'm trying to kill is in the INACTIVE state. I'm trying to maintain a single connection to the database, so when user doesn't do any activity and doesn't issue any SQL requests, the status of the session may turn to INACTIVE, correct? But in this case what is wrong in killing an inactive session?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the program is waiting for rollback to complete.

Comment: What program do you mean? Oracle process? Or my application? 
Is there any way I can check that it really waits for rollback to complete?

Comment: AFAIK, the 'immediate' version of session kill triggers rollback as well, isn't it? However I don't seem to have this delay if session was killed with the 'immediate' keyword.